# Passing concat query parameters to SQL OPENQUERY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Due to the constraints within the workplace I have to use a local stored procedure to call another remote stored proc on a linked sql server, however the problem lies in passing a necessary parameter to the remote stored proc.

This is the query I constructed:

```
select *
from OPENQUERY([REMOTE_SRVR],'exec db.dbo.dwStoredProc_sp ''@id''')
```

In order to pass `@id` to the remote stored proc I understand I could concatenate the above as a string and then use `exec`

Something along the lines of:

```
set @query = 'select * from OPENQUERY([REMOTE_SRVR], ''EXEC db.dbo.dwStoredProc_sp '' @id '''''
exec(@query)
```

I cannot get the local stored proc to successfully call the other. The single quote mess doesn't help!

I get the error: `Could not find stored procedure 's'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help with the quote mess I like to do this in steps. It is more code but easier to understand. I am not sure from your example if @id is an integer. In that case you can lose the double quotes around `__ID__`.

```
set @query = 'EXEC db.dbo.dwStoredProc_sp ''__ID__'''
set @query = REPLACE(@query,'__ID__',@id)
set @query = REPLACE(@query,'''','''''')
set @query = REPLACE('SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([REMOTE_SRVR], ''__REMOTEQUERY__'')','__REMOTEQUERY__',@query)
```

Comment: Just to clarify `@id` will be a string. I'll try this breakdown approach thanks.

Comment: This works great, however I'm trying to use `sp_executesql` now for safety.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid dynamic queries by simply by using `EXEC (..., ParamValue) AT LinkedServer` (see [product's documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx), example [L. Using a parameter with EXECUTE and AT linked_server_name]):

1) On target server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Proc1( @id NVARCHAR(50) )
AS 
SELECT @id AS [id];
GO
```

2) On the source server you create the linked server and then you can call the stored procedure using `EXEC ... AT ...` syntax:

```
DECLARE @p1 NVARCHAR(50);
SET @p1 = N'DROP TABLE dbo.CocoJambo'
EXECUTE (N'dbo.Proc1 ? ' , @p1 ) AT LOCALINKEDSEREV
```

Output:

```
id
------------------------
DROP TABLE dbo.CocoJambo
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I tried this before `openquery` and did not succeed because the linked server is not configured for RPC - apparently.

Comment: You have to enable `RPC out` for the linked server: `"RPC Out
Enables RPC to the specified server."` [ref: "RPC Out
Enables RPC to the specified server"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186839(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: It's not possible to have that configured - or at least any time soon - so I'm attempting to use `sp_executesql`

Comment: @Lee: you have to replace `LOCALINKEDSERVER` with server used by `OPENQUERY`: `[REMOTE_SRVR]`. Simply using `sp_executesql` will not protect you against SQL injections. `sp_executesql` will defend you against this type of attacks if `sp_executesql` is used with parameters. But this is not the case for above solution. And `OPENQUERY` / `OPENROWSET` have a nasty behavior when stored procedure have to execute non-SELECT statements.